# ASP.NET MVC [RegularExpression] Attribute Not Functioning on Entire String Match

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I can't seem to find a similar topic on Stack Overflow regarding this, so here goes:

Why is it when I specify against my ASP.NET MVC view model class the following definition:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"\A\d{3,4}\Z",
   ErrorMessage = "The security code (CVN) must be between 3 - 4 digits long.")]
[Display(Name = "Card Security Code (CVN)")]
public string CardCVN { get; set; }
```

That on my unobtrusive client side validation test the regular expression cannot be validated? (and subsequently displays a form field error).

It seems as soon as my regex is changed to `[RegularExpression(@"\d{3,4}"...` removing the entire string matching technique, it matches perfectly? and it seems the jquery validation that renders, even though it doesn't apply `\A` or `\Z` it matches only on entire string match anyway (doing what I originally needed!); Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client side, the regex is executed by JavaScript, and JS doesn't support `\A`, `\Z` or `\z`.  You could use `^` and `$` instead, but you shouldn't need to.  Regexes used in validators are usually anchored at both ends automatically.  I'm pretty sure that's the case with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Interesting, one would imagine ASP.NET MVC truly should have converted it then :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead: `@"^\d{3,4}$"`

`^` - start of string.

`$` - end of string.

Comment: You missed the \ on \d. However thanks for the response. I will award Alan with the points as he explained his response though.