# Regex.Match is true but [RegularExpression] attribute gives error

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4, user-accounts

I have a regular expression:

```
^(?=.*\p{N})
```

(which I copied from SO answer with many upvotes)
and an attribute on `Password` property like so:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*\p{N})", ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least one number")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

However, it gives that error when it comes to the registration method. Meanwhile in `Immediate window` this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(model.Password, @"^(?=.*\p{N})")
```

returns true.

Not sure if useful, but the password I am trying is `yesman69`.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? On the browser client-side or in the server-side code?

Comment: @Jasen Inside the Register method on the server side the `ModelState` contains an error in the list of errors for `Password` (other fields' error lists are empty) which says `Password must contain at least one number`

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC \[RegularExpression\] Attribute Not Functioning on Entire String Match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274585/asp-net-mvc-regularexpression-attribute-not-functioning-on-entire-string-match)